# CSS menu child align

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Need some help with a drop down menu.
I made a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bLL0rmbd/
I want to align the hover submenu like in the image:

[image: http://i58.tinypic.com/2v865pl.jpg]

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">SubMenu 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SubMenu 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SubMenu 3</a></li>
                </ul>       
            </li>                 
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
    #wrapper {padding: 0; margin: 30px}

    #navbar ul {
        padding: 0; 
        margin:0px; 
        list-style: none; 
        float:left; 
        background:#FF6;
    }
    #navbar ul li { display: inline-block; margin-right:20px;}
    #navbar ul li a {text-decoration:none;}
    #navbar ul ul { 
        position:absolute;
        display: none;
    }
    #navbar ul ul li {display:block;}

    #navbar ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block; 
        background-color:#CFC;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: so you want to start the sub menu right after the menu 2's text?

Comment: No, i want to align the right side of the submenu to the right side of his parrent, "Menu 3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope this works for you .

```
     #navbar ul {
padding: 0; 
  margin:0px; 
  list-style: none; 
 float:left; 
    background:#FF6;
  position: relative;

        }
    #navbar ul ul { 
position:absolute;
display: none;
  right: 0;
 top: 100%;
    }
```

I have only aded 3 lines of code pos: relative on ul and absolute value on dropdown.

Or you can set pos: relative to #navbar li and change absolute value for dropdown accrding to wish.

Cheers

[Link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sabipu/bLL0rmbd/2/)

Comment: Thank you for your fast answers. One more question though. When i hover the submenu, i want the background parrent to be green to, like the child menu.

Comment: pleasures.!! I didnt get you exactly, but I hope you want somthing like this. http://jsfiddle.net/sabipu/bLL0rmbd/7/ or somthing else ? or while hovering you can make the whole yellow background of ul go green by adding ul:hover ( change the bg-color)

Comment: When i keep the cursor over Submenu1, 2, 3 i want "Menu 3" background to be green

Comment: ohh , so you can add bg-color on li: hover
http://jsfiddle.net/sabipu/bLL0rmbd/12/

Comment: Thank you so much guys for your help. Amazing community here.

Answer (score 0):

Add a negative `margin-left` to the sub menu and it should work:

```
#navbar ul li:hover > ul 
{   display: block; 
    background-color:#CFC;
    margin-left:-25px;                                            
}
```

Updated fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/bLL0rmbd/3/

Answer (score 0):

You this css here

```
  #navbar ul {
  padding: 0; 
  margin:0px; 
  float:left; 
  background:#CFC;
  position: relative;
  }

 #navbar ul ul { 
  position:absolute;
  display: none;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
  }
```

[Check the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bLL0rmbd/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS style for your recent question:

```
li:hover{background-color:#CFC;}

#navbar ul li:hover > ul 
{   display: block; 
    background-color:#CFC;
    margin-left:-25px;                                            
}
```

Check Out this fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/bLL0rmbd/11/

Answer (score 0):

[try this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bLL0rmbd/13/5/)

```
#navbar ul {
padding: 0; 
margin:0px; 
list-style: none; 
float:left; 
background:#FF6;
position: relative;
}
#navbar ul ul { 
position:absolute;
display: none;
right: 0;
top: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add a bit more information about your solution.